# Linux Mint 18.3 x64 no Wi-Fi after clean install

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, realtek

After installing Linux Mint on my new PC I found that the Wi-Fi was not even showing.

If I run `iwconfig` I get:

```
lo                no wireless extensions
enp0s20fou1       no wireless extensions
enpls0            no wireless extensions
```

while, with `lspci -nn` I get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5914] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5917] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d18] (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d1b] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d4e] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Device [1c5c:1527]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
```

Here, just the network part, with `lspci -nn | grep -i network` I get

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
```

And finally this is the output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:    Host: HP-ProBook-450-G5 Kernel: 4.10.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.6 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: HP (portable) product: HP ProBook 450 G5
           Mobo: HP model: 837D v: KBC Version 02.2A.00 Bios: HP v: Q85 Ver. 01.02.05 date: 03/12/2018
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-8550U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 15936
           clock speeds: max: 4000 MHz 1: 770 MHz 2: 735 MHz 3: 643 MHz 4: 779 MHz 5: 746 MHz 6: 786 MHz
           7: 716 MHz 8: 706 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5917 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Kabylake GT1.5 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device 9d71 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 Sound: ALSA v: k4.10.0-38-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek Device b822 port: 3000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: N/A state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: NA (-) ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: N/A size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 219G used: 5.7G (3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.07GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 36.0C mobo: 0.0C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 230 Uptime: 27 min Memory: 1184.6/15938.7MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to boot live media with a different kernel version and see if that resolves it. If it does, than it's another fubared kernel.

Comment: @ajeh I made this try before reading your comment, 'cause I was having troubles compiling a realtek driver, while following another guide. Updating the kernel fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the kernel from 4.10 to 4.17 fixed it.
Probably the corresponding driver for the wifi adapter, was not included in the old release of the kernel.

Comment: Unfortunately this happens all the time, stranding new installs w/o network access. Good it resolved this quickly. Someone should learn to test before releasing, but I am preaching to a choir for too long.

Comment: @ajeh It is open source, you can always volunteer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro You are justifying unjustifiable. Open source developers' persistent refusal to test and debug, while insisting on releasing their untested code full of bugs into the world is an obscene demonstration of irresponsibility. On top of that many of those who develop bugged code are filthy rich compared with those, whose systems they bring down, but they still moan that they cannot test everything, while there is only a tiny handful of Ethernet and WiFi chipsets out there, Realtek being absolute market leader. 99% of Linux users never use 99% of functionality shoved down our throats.

Comment: yet Linux industry is pumping out new releases at alarming rate, offering nothing of value, while breaking good functionality and focusing mainly on UI rewrites and icon repainting. It literally came down to searching for distros with ethical and careful maintainers and protecting investment of time into system building from new releases. This is a very sad state of affairs. I offer praise and vote for good software with a $ when due, but I will not be silent about horrid attitude of many open source developers.